# Bitcoin integration api for website

Tags: api

i'm interested making a website allowing users to send and withdraw btc from it (every user will have private address on the site) , is there any suggestions of api i could use that will store the bitcoins on the server and not some third part service that stores the btc?

Comment: Why do you need to store user's bitcoin? What is the use case?

Comment: @MatthewStannard Thinking of making an bitcoin exchange to other alt coins, but as start i want to work on the bitcoin receive and withdraw first

Comment: Are you working with have a team of developers who have Information Security experience?

Comment: @MatthewStannard Planning to hire an expert to make all the needed security when i'm done with my part :)

Comment: You can't add security to an insecure system after it has been built. If you're certain you want to take on the responsibility of handling customers' funds, then I would work with a team of information security experts from the beginning and throughout the lifetime of your service.

Comment: @MatthewStannard does one developer is able to know both the site developing part and also doing the security?

Comment: It is possible that a single person has the expertise to build both the site and implement the necessary security requirements. But is is rare.

Comment: @MatthewStannard could you give an example of some common breach that requires some special security requirements?

Comment: As this is a separate question you should consider asking an new question. Try asking about common causes of data breaches over at https://security.stackexchange.com/.